# RSA Profiling Stop

Tags: eclipse, profiling, websphere, rsa

Im using IBM RSA. I accidentally ran my application in Profiling Mode. Since then I couldn't start my application in Normal Mode or Debug Mode. Please help me in this .

I couldn't find Servers in Windows>Preferences too.

Im using Websphere Access Server 6.1

Answer (score 2):

It is as simple as this: remove `-agentlib:getClasses` from the generic JVM args.

Comment: True for WebSphere Application Server base 8.5.5.6, too.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about Websphere Access Server, but did you try to when into the menu (Run > Run Configurations ... ) ?

Or eventualy (Windows > Show view > Servers), right click on you server and click Start.

?

Let me know if it's helpfull.